# Case Statement overriding other case

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

In the following case statement, the value '1' is being assigned to those who have a Start Term of September 2019 whereas the value '3' should be assigned.

Additionally, those that have a L._Stage of 'not interested' are being included in the search despite being ruled out in the query.

```
SELECT
U.*,
L.ID AS Lead_ID,

CASE

WHEN (L.Age_Change > 180) OR (L.Age_Change IS NULL AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL) AND
(L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%' AND
 L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%') AND
(L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%' AND  
 L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%' AND 
 L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%') THEN '1' 

WHEN (L._Stage IS NULL AND L.Created_Date < DATEADD(day,-45, GETDATE()) AND 
(L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%' AND 
 L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%' AND 
 L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%') THEN '2'

WHEN (L.Age_Change > 180) OR (L.Age_Change IS NULL AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL) AND
(L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%' AND
 L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%') AND
(L.Start_Term LIKE '%September 2019%' AND 
 L.Start_Term LIKE '%September 2020%' AND 
 L.Start_Term LIKE '%September 2021%') THEN '3'

 ELSE NULL END AS Case_Logic
```

**EDIT**

I've updated the field L.Age_Change to a field which accepts INT and this change is reflected in the query above.

Sample data:

```
Lead ID  L.Age_Change L._Stage    L.Start_Term     Expected Case Logic
0001     200          Interested  September 2018   '1'
0002     NULL         Interested  September 2018   '1'
0003     NULL         Interested  September 2019   '3'
0004     182          Interested  September 2019   '3'
0005     250          Interested  September 2020   '3'
```

In the situation above, '0003','0004' and '0005' are all assigned a case logic value of '1' as opposed to '3'.

Any guidance on the issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you provide some sample data rows?

Comment: This is your third question on the query and you have never provided test data.  VTC

Comment: @Paparazzi the platform im using does not allow me to return data, it only allows me to create and run a query

Comment: @tablecloth26 A query does return data.

Comment: @tablecloth26 you don't have to give us your actual data , made up sample data which proves your point or illustrates your problem would help.

Comment: You are mixing `OR` and `AND` without parenthesis. Your first case will evaluate to `TRUE` if left of first OR is true without taking into account any other condition.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @tablecloth26 could you please tell us L.Start_Term datatype ? is it VARCHAR or DATE?  and for L._Stage does it contain one value for each row ? is it a part of string or there is no other strings with it ?

Comment: @JacobH I've now added sample data rows in the edit

Comment: @iSR5 L.Start_Term is a VARCHAR and L._Stage only contains one value for each row. I've added sample data to the edit if you want to see what the data looks like

Comment: @tablecloth26 check my answer, I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

There are differences in your `CASE` statements besides just `Start_Term`.  In `CASE 3` you are using `L.Age_Last__Stage_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE())`, and in `CASE 1` you are using `(L.Age_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE()))`

So change it to the below statement, and if returns the right result, then you know it's because you are mixing up `L.Age_Change` and `L.Age_Last__Stage_Change` and you need to change your logic.

```
WHEN (L.Age_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE())) OR (L.Age_Change IS NULL 
AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL) AND
(L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%' AND
 L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%') AND
(L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%' AND  
 L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%' AND 
 L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%') THEN '1' 

WHEN (L._Stage IS NULL AND L.Created_Date < DATEADD(day,-45, GETDATE()) AND 
(L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%' AND 
 L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%' AND 
 L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%') THEN '2'

WHEN (L.Age_Last__Stage_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE())) OR 
(L.Age_Last__Stage_Change IS NULL AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL) AND
(L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%' AND
 L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%') AND
(L.Start_Term LIKE '%September 2019%' AND 
 L.Start_Term LIKE '%September 2020%' AND 
 L.Start_Term LIKE '%September 2021%') THEN '3'
```

Comment: Difference is also in the last groups: (L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%' AND  L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%' AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%') for 1st and (L.Start_Term LIKE '%September 2019%' AND L.Start_Term LIKE '%September 2020%' AND L.Start_Term LIKE '%September 2021%') for 3rd. There are some additional NOTs in the first.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response! i accidentally uploaded the wrong query so i've made the correct amendments but still no resolution :(

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. If you indent everything it is much easier to see where the mistake is:

```
CASE
    WHEN (
                L.Age_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE()) 
            OR  (L.Age_Change IS NULL AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL)
         ) 
        AND (
                    L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%' 
                AND L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%' 
                AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%'
                AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%' 
                AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%'
            ) THEN '1' 

    WHEN        L._Stage IS NULL AND L.Created_Date < DATEADD(day,-45, GETDATE()) 
            AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%' 
            AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%' 
            AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%' THEN '2'

    WHEN (
                L.Age_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE()) 
            OR (L.Age_Change IS NULL AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL)
         ) 
        AND (
                    L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%' 
                AND L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%') 
                AND (
                            L.Start_Term LIKE '%September 2019%' 
                        OR  L.Start_Term LIKE '%September 2020%' --Changed AND to OR, because an value cannot be LIKE '%September 2019%' AND LIKE '%September 2020%', it's one or the other (I assume)
                        OR  L.Start_Term LIKE '%September 2021%'
                    )
            ) THEN '3'

 ELSE NULL 
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `OR` and `AND` condition without use of brackets between them which is never a good idea. `AND` will take precedence and your query when written more readable, will look like this:

```
WHEN 
L.Age_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE())    
OR 
(
  L.Age_Change IS NULL 
  AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL 
  AND L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%' 
  AND L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%' 
  AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%' 
  AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%' 
  AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%'
) 
THEN '1'
```

and will evaluate to `TRUE` if first part is true OR if everything else is true.

You probably want `OR` condition to be in brackets for something like:

```
WHEN 
(
   L.Age_Change < DATEADD(day,-180, GETDATE()) 
   OR 
   L.Age_Change IS NULL
)
AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL 
AND L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Not Interested%' 
AND L._Stage NOT LIKE '%Duplicate%' 
AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2019%' 
AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2020%' 
AND L.Start_Term NOT LIKE '%September 2021%'
THEN '1'
```

and same in third case

Also note that using `AND/OR` on the beginning of row and proper indents for every bracket can help you not make mistakes.

Comment: Still no luck. It now doesnt assign it a value of 1 or 3

Answer (score 0):

Since Case 1 and 3 have similarities, maybe if we combine them into one nested case will be a better approach.

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT
L.Lead_ID,
L.Age_Change, 
L._Stage, 
L.Start_Term,
CASE
    WHEN 
        (L.Age_Change > 180 OR L.Age_Change IS NULL )
    AND L._Stage IS NOT NULL
    AND L._Stage NOT IN('Not Interested', 'Duplicate')
    THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN  L.Start_Term NOT IN('September 2019', 'September 2020', 'September 2021') THEN 1
            WHEN  L.Start_Term IN('September 2019', 'September 2020', 'September 2021') THEN 3
        END
    WHEN 
        L.Age_Change BETWEEN 45 AND 180
    AND L._Stage IS NULL
    AND L.Start_Term IN('September 2019', 'September 2020', 'September 2021')   
    THEN 2
    ELSE NULL 
END AS Case_Logic
FROM test L
```

Results:

```
| Lead_ID | Age_Change |         _Stage |     Start_Term | Case_Logic |
|---------|------------|----------------|----------------|------------|
|       1 |        200 |     Interested | September 2018 |          1 |
|       2 |     (null) |     Interested | September 2018 |          1 |
|       3 |     (null) |     Interested | September 2019 |          3 |
|       4 |        182 |     Interested | September 2019 |          3 |
|       5 |        250 |     Interested | September 2020 |          3 |
```

This would avoid you using OR and also keep your query short rather than repeating conditions on the same column (even if it has differences).

We could even make it shorter if we know the schema and have an appropriate sample to test.

**UPDATE:**

Since you cleared that `_Stage` and `Start_Term` are both `VARCHAR` and they're not a part of any other string. 
You could use the above solution, as `LIKE` would be better if the phrase would be a part of another string (like sentences) OR you don't know the exact match. But `IN` would do the same thing if (AND ONLY if) is it the exact match.

You could still use any of them `LIKE` or `IN`, it's just depends on your data and which works better with it.

NOTE Since you didn't provide enough sample to cover the third case (case#2) I tried to replicate the case and the conditions from your query I added to the provided, and everything will works fine with the sample logic.

Demo : [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7c17d/1)

Comment: You can't replace the `OR LIKE ` with `IN`, `IN` doesn't work that way.

Comment: @HoneyBadger sorry, forgot to remove the wildcard symbol from the strings. As for IN() it should work just fine.

Comment: I doubt it, `LIKE` was used because it's only part of the string that'll match.

Comment: @HoneyBadger come to think of it, for L._Stage, yes I agree and maybe even some fixed phrases that are commonly used in their system (auto generated from third-party source), but for L.Start_Term!, it's possible to be even a date and not varchar datatype, which is possible to be treated wrongly as a varchar in the first place. I'll try to validate that with the OP.